# Show all columns with rank

Tags: oracle, top-n

Is it possible to show all the columns of the table in oracle along with the column that will show distinct rank like using dense_rank()? If yes please do let me know the solution.

Comment: On what basis are you going to assign rank to them? Please care to explain.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. `SELECT yourtable.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (...) FROM yourtable;` Please share more information and we can give more help.

Comment: Thanks JNevil. I got the result. Really appreciate.

Comment: @KaushikNayak...I want the odd number of records which I have done with decode but I was not getting the result using analytical functions.